# Colcon build causes Drake errors for the latest Drake release

Tags: drake

I recently updated Drake using the latest tar file (drake-1.25.0-jammy.tar.gz).  When I subsequently ran colcon build, I got the following errors which I have not seen before.   Thx.[Colcon build errors with latest version of Drake
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9bOS.png)[Errors2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmf3i.png)
I went back to the previous version of Drake and these errors disappeared.  A colleague checked me on this and got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

What version of `drake-ros` are you using (e.g., what is the git hash, or the date of its latest commit?).

To my eye, it looks like you're using an ancient checkout of `drake-ros`.

Please try again with an up-to-date version?

Also: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I think I am using drake-ros version 0.1.0. (I got this from drake-ros package.xml): <?xml version="1.0"?> <package format="2"> <name>drake_ros</name> <version>0.1.0</version> <description>Drake systems to leverage core ROS 2 functionality.</description> 

Is drake-ros something I need to update independently of drake? (So it's not updated automatically when I update Drake?). Apologies for the image upload. This is my first time posting a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The package.xml version turns out to be unhelpful -- there are no numbered releases, so the important point is which git revision you are using.
Yes, drake-ros is independent of drake and you should update it to the latest available commit from git.